# Python Reddit Comment Keyword Search

Tags: python

I am building a scraper that searches reddit comments for keywords. I am having two problems 
Problem 1. in order to build the commentforest I  need to get the submission_id from the comment so I can pull all of the comments related to that submission.I am having trouble figuring out how to get the submission id.

problem 2. for some reason every time I run this code it gives me new comments that include the keywords (I am assuming this is just because new comments have been added) BUT some of the old comments arent showing up when i run the code again. this is supposed to pull ALL the comments that match my keyword from the subreddit what am i doing wrong?

```
from psaw import PushshiftAPI
from datetime import datetime, timezone, timedelta
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
api = PushshiftAPI()

comments = api.search_comments(q='OP', subreddit='askreddit')

max_response_cache = 1000
cache = []

commentcount = 0

for c in comments:
    cache.append(c)
    commentcount += 1
    print (f' comment {commentcount}: {c.body}')
```

I want the code to print out the submission id related to the comments and I want to be able to pull all the comments that match my keywords.